# NodeJS Express nested input body object validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express

I have some trouble validating my nested object request body with "express-validator" package. Let's say we have a method to collect user input with a body like this :

```
{
    "general": {
        "sessionId": "a2957207-e033-49e7-b9da-1c5f946a1074",
        "os": "android",
        "vendor": "htc"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "target": "logPageVisits",
            "pageName": "users/packages",
            "engagementTime": 350
        }
    ]
}
```

express-validator only offers validation like this :

```
req.checkBody('engagementTime')
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage('Engagement-Time is required')
```

It seems there's no clean way to validated nested objects like this :

```
req.checkBody('data.engagementTime')
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage('Engagement-Time is required')
```

I've found an closed issue on [Github](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/128)! but it doesn't fulfill my concerns!

Any better suggestions?

Comment: hey, i'm having the same problem but having a hard time finding a solution. Did you figure it out ?

Comment: Hi, eventually I ended up writing my own validation method and it worked well
here's just a hint : 

`if (typeof validationObject.field !== validationObject.filter) {
        validationErrors = `${validationObject.fieldName} must be type of ${validationObject.filter}`;
    }`

Comment: yeah that could work. meanwhile i'm trying to use the checkSchema, check it out its interesting.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention for nested objects I had to use a for loop, I checked the type of input variable and in case of objects or arrays I looped through elements.

Comment: finally it worked just fine, i just made a mistake in writing the names. In fact this is the body: {
  payload: {
    identifier: 'xxxxx',
    type: false,
    data: { name: 'xxx' }
  }
}
so i just have to write check('payload.data.name'), at first I was forgetting "payload"

Answer (score 3):

I am a bit late, but here is what you can do as of v6.12.0. To validate a schema, you can use `checkSchema` method:

```js
const { checkSchema } = require('express-validator');

checkSchema({
  'general': {
    in: 'body', // the location of the field
    exists: {
      errorMessage: 'Field `general` cannot be empty',
      bail: true
    },
    isObject: {
      errorMessage: 'Field `general` must be an object',
      bail: true
    }
  },
  // to check a nested object field use `object.nestedField` notation
  'general.sessionId': {
    trim: true,
    isString: {
      errorMessage: 'Field `sessionId` must be a string',
      bail: true
    }
  },
  'data': {
    in: 'body', 
    exists: {
      errorMessage: 'Field `data` cannot be empty',
      bail: true
    },
    isArray: {
      errorMessage: 'Field `data` must be an array',
      bail: true
    }
  },
  // use `*` to loop through an array
  'data.*.engagementTime': { 
    notEmpty: {
      errorMessage: 'Field `engagementTime` should not be empty',
      bail: true
    }
  }
})
```

References:

- [Express Validator: Schema Validation](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/schema-validation.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can always create your custom [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) for express.
For example, in your case, very simplified it would look like this:

```
const checkNestedBodyMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const { data } = req.body;

  // As I see, here is array in data, so we use simple find
  const engTimeInArr = data.find(d => d.engagementTime);

  if(!engTimeInArr){
    return res.status(400).send('Engagement-Time is required');
  }

  next();
}
```

And then use it in your route:

```
app.post('/some-route', checkNestedBodyMiddleware, (req, res) => {
   // your route logic here.
})
```

So, in this case you hide validation logic in middleware and can assign any number of middlewares to route.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.*.` for iterating this

```
req.checkBody('data.*.engagementTime')
         .notEmpty()
         .withMessage('Engagement-Time is required')
```